# Angular Export Data in mat-table containing image

Tags: angular, excel, export

I have mat-table with many cells, one of cells is

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iV....">
```

how to export table to excel file?

Answer (score 0):

I guess easiest way would be to use a dedicated libary for such a thing. E.g https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-table-exporter

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mte-demo

Seems that it would support output data encoding so you could in theory also export images to excel.

Comment: I saw this library before but how can I export if cells contain images.. I have tried like this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mte-demo-5scf7j) but didn't work.. Any example.

Comment: Someone claims to have solved it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62075877/15439733