# Mat-icon doesn't export in excel sheet?

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material, export-to-excel, mat-icon

I have used mat-icons to show in table in my project. but while exporting table to Excel or CSV changes to mat icon name instead of icon. I have attached code and image for more understanding.

[image: icon display in web view]

[image: icon changes to name in Excel export]

mat-icon code

```
 <i class="material-icons col-green">arrow_upward</i>
```

I have also tried with

```
<mat-icon class="col-green">arrow_upward</mat-icon>
```

here's my export table code

```
exportTable(fileType = "xlsx") {
    this.matTableExporter.exportTable(fileType, { fileName: this.tabData.title, sheet: this.tabData.title });
}
```

Comment: Probably have to send the image blob with the row. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62075877/15439733